# Let $B=\{f\in C[0,1] :\Vert f\Vert_{\infty} \leq 1\}$. Find all $f\in B$ such that $f=(g+h)/2$

Tags: real-analysis

Question says

> For $(C[0,1], \Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty})$, let $B=\{f\in C[0,1] :
>  \Vert f\Vert_{\infty} \leq 1\}$. Find all $f\in B$ such that
> there exist $g,h\in B$, $g\neq h$, with $f=\frac{g+h}{2}$

I studied some graphs and I feel that for $f \equiv 1$ and $f \equiv -1$, we can't find such $g,h, g\neq h$ which gives $f=\frac{g+h}{2}$ as only choice for $g$ and $h$ left is to be identically equal to  $1$ or $-1$, in respective case. For all other cases, we can increase and decrease function $f$ little bit(for those $x$ such that $\Vert f(x)\Vert \neq 1$) so as to get average equal to $f$. I can sketch that but not able to put it mathematically. Am I correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Define $g(x)=f(x)+\varepsilon(x),~~h(x)=f(x)-\varepsilon(x)$, where $\varepsilon(x)$ is some suitable continuous function which is not everywhere $0$ such that both of the above functions are still bounded by $1$ and $-1$. Show that such a function exists exactly in the cases you mentioned, preferably by giving an explicit construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ has a point $x$ such that $-1<f(x)<1$. Then, by continuity of $f$, there is a whole interval about $x$, say $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ for which this is true. Let $s:=\max\{1-|f(t)|:x-\delta\le t\le x+\delta\}>0$.

Let $g(t):=f(t)+r(t-x)$ and $h(t):=f(t)-r(t-x)$ where $r(t)=s(1-\min(1,|t|))$ is the tent function centered at zero with height $s$. Then clearly $f=\frac{g+h}{2}$ and $|g(t)|\le|f(t)|+s\le1$; similarly for $h$. Hence $g,h\in B$ and $g\ne h$, with the required properties.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for a rigorous proof: Suppose $|f(c)| <1$ for some $c$. Let $r=1-|f(c)|$. Let $g_n$ be a piece-wise linear function such that $g_n(c)=\frac r 2$ and $g_n(x)=0$ for $|x-c| \geq \frac 1 n$. [Draw a picture.] Then $f=\frac {(f+g_n) +(f-g_n)} 2$  and $|f(x)\pm g_n (x)| \leq 1$ for all $x$ provided $n$ is large enough.